# .Net Core Web API equal paths for different roles

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to have multiple routes with the same path but for different types of users:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/products")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public IActionResult ListProducts()
   {
           // ...
   }

   [HttpGet("/products")]
   [Authorize(Roles = "Supervisor")]
   public IActionResult ListProducts()
   {
           // ...
   }
}
```

But i am getting multiple route match error. Is there any way to have multiple endpoint with the same name, but for different roles?

Comment: Could you have a single route that allowed everybody, and then redirected to one of two different routes (one for Admin, one for Supervisor)?

Comment: that's what i am trying to avoid :)

Comment: That is the simplest option, otherwise you would need to create an interceptor, possibly an action constraint ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#understanding-iactionconstraint))

Comment: What if the user has both roles?

Comment: @DavidG that is exacly what i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I ended up defining my own IActionContraint to solve the route matching problem:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#understanding-iactionconstraint)
Thank you to @DavidG for the answer.

Comment: Could you please explain how it is actually implemented?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the user role as a input parameter to perticular method. Then do anything considering that role value.

```
    public IActionResult ListProducts(String role) { 
if(role=="Administrator")
{}
else if(...)// ... }
```